# How to switch scenes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, scene

I have looked on many pages to try and find out how to switch scenes but I have been unsuccessful.

I have a calculator and my goal is to select a menu option to change Calculators(ie: basic and scientific). Right now I am just testing so here is my code relevant to this question thus far (I am using Scene Builder):

```
@FXML private MenuItem basic;
@FXML private MenuItem testSwitch;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch( args );

}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
   Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(
           getClass().getResource( "calculator.fxml" ) );

   Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.setTitle( "Calculator" );
   primaryStage.show();

}
@FXML
public void handleMenuOption(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource()==basic)
    {
        changeScene("calculator.fxml");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==testSwitch)
    {
        changeScene("TestSwitch.fxml");
    }
}
public void changeScene(String fxml) 
{
    //this prints out
    System.out.println(fxml);
}
```

**EDIT**
I've tried quite a few things already. No matter what, I always get this NullPointerException. I have a feeling it may have to do with setting something in scene builder but I just have not been able to find an answer

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at    com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at CalculatorMain.changeScene(CalculatorMain.java:75)
at CalculatorMain.handleMenuOption(CalculatorMain.java:64)
... 53 more




at CalculatorMain.changeScene(CalculatorMain.java:75)
This is at:stage . getScene() . setRoot(pane);


at CalculatorMain.handleMenuOption(CalculatorMain.java:64)
This is at:changeScene ("TestSwitch.fxml");
```

WORKING CODE:

I played around using suggestions below and used this code to make it work:

```
private Stage stage;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch( args );
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    this.stage = primaryStage;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
            .getResource("calculator.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
    BasicCalculatorView controller = (BasicCalculatorView)loader.getController();
    controller.setModel(new BasicCalculatorModelTest(controller));
    controller.setLogic(this);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void switchScene(String fxmlFile)
{

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
            .getResource(fxmlFile));
    Parent root;
    try 
    {
        root = (Parent)loader.load();
        if(fxmlFile.equals("calculator.fxml"))
        {
            BasicCalculatorView controller = (BasicCalculatorView)loader.getController();
            controller.setModel(new BasicCalculatorModelTest(controller));
            controller.setLogic(this);
        }
        else if(fxmlFile.equals("TestSwitch.fxml"))
        {
            TestSwitch controller = (TestSwitch)loader.getController();
            controller.setLogic(this);
        }
        this.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I wrote this controller to keep track of the different scenegraphes.

```
public class ScreenController {
    private HashMap<String, Pane> screenMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Scene main;

    public ScreenController(Scene main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    protected void addScreen(String name, Pane pane){
         screenMap.put(name, pane);
    }

    protected void removeScreen(String name){
        screenMap.remove(name);
    }

    protected void activate(String name){
        main.setRoot( screenMap.get(name) );
    }
}
```

So I can write:

```
ScreenController screenController = new ScreenController(scene);
screenController.add("calculator", FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource( "calculator.fxml" )));
screenController.add("testSwitch", FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource( "TestSwitch.fxml" )));
screenController.activate("calculator");
```

This was a workaround for a fullscreen application, where the MacOS fullscreen transition was shown every time a stage switches its scene.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of switching `Scenes`, switch a root node on already existing `Scene`

Comment: I have tried this but I keep getting a null pointer exception. After getting two comments about the same thing I decided to post my exception message, see above.

Comment: In your code you're mixing `Application` and FXML controller concepts. Each have different initialization lifecycle. FXML controllers are based on dependency injection principle and initialization should be done in the `init` method. Read up on FXML controllers. You can also see the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method

Comment: So how would I switch a scene. I tried using the init method and setting a string parameter. If I passed in a string such as "test" and use a syso to print out the result, it would print out test. But if I passed in a string with the FXML file and tried to set a scene, it would give me a null pointer exception

Answer (score 7):

If you want to go along with changing the scene you would do it like this (note that the Stage is a member of the application):

```
private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ...
}

public void changeScene(String fxml){
    Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(
           getClass().getResource(fxml));

   Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
}
```

However as already pointed out by @Eugene_Ryzhikov it is a better solution to just change the root content of the existing scene:

```
public void changeScene(String fxml){
    Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(
           getClass().getResource(fxml));

   primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(pane);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I keep getting a null pointer exception. After getting two comments about the same thing I decided to post my exception message, see above.

Comment: What is the code at the line where you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Above I have added the exception I got and there are notes at the bottom. But I tired a couple similar examples without using Scene Builder and it worked perfectly fine so it is for sure something with Scene Builder

Comment: Is it possible that the stage that is passed as parameter in the `start` method is not assigned to the member `primaryStage`? This would result in a `NullPointerException` on line `primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(pane)`. I updated the code example to include the fragment for the `start` method.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old post. Why do you do `this.primaryStage = primaryStage;`? Why not just ignore the `start()` method argument and do everything with `this.primaryStage`?

Comment: To change the scene you need a method (`changeScene`) in that method you need a reference to the `Stage`, that is passed in when the application is started. The `start` method is called on application start.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran to the same issue and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805134/7182504) solved my issue perfectly while being short and clean.

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
System.out.println("You clicked me!");
label.setText("Hello World!");
//Here I want to swap the screen!

Stage stageTheEventSourceNodeBelongs = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
// OR
Stage stageTheLabelBelongs = (Stage) label.getScene().getWindow();
// these two of them return the same stage
// Swap screen
stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane()));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that makes switching Scenes really simple. You just pick a unique ID for each scene of type Integer, then you add scenes with one line of code. When you need to show a scene, you can do so from any class in your project by calling that method and passing it the the ID of the scene.

[You can find the library here](https://github.com/EasyG0ing1/Switcher) along with the Maven import xml.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way (This avoids re-loading scene):

**In main Application class:**

1. Create a private static attribute to store your stage:

   ```java
   private static Stage primaryStage;
   ```
2. Assign stage to your primaryStage in overridden `start(Stage stage)` method:

   ```java
   primaryStage = stage;
   ```
3. Create static method changeScene

   ```
    public static void  changeScene(String fxml) throws IOException {
      Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(GameApplication.class.getResource(fxml)));
      primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(pane);
   ```

This method you can use wherever you want, in any class:

Example:

```
MainApplication.changeScene("next-scene-view.fxml");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
TypesController.java
package todoapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TypesController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private CheckBox c1;
@FXML
private CheckBox c2;
public void clicked(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
Parent home_page_parent =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AddDcuFXML.fxml"));
Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page_parent);
Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
app_stage.hide(); //optional
app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
app_stage.show();
}
public void clicked1(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
Parent home_page_parent =   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AddDcuFXML.fxml"));
    Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page_parent);
    Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
   app_stage.hide(); //optional
   app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
   app_stage.show();
   }
  @Override
  public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  } }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be cool with such a long code example.

Comment: @ChristianM I like the way you have given feedback on this answer..:-)

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="386.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="todoapp.TypesController">
<children>
  <CheckBox fx:id="c1" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="125.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clicked" text="ADD dcu" />
  <CheckBox fx:id="c2" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="177.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clicked1" text="Display dcu" />
  <Label layoutX="31.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="276.0" text="Choose any one of the options" textFill="#1b29cd">
     <font>
        <Font name="Arial Bold" size="18.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
</children>
```

Comment: please edit your first answer and add the snippets from the other answers (plus explain how/why they solve the problem as suggested in the comment)

Comment: Just so you know I posted this like 2 years ago. I think all I did was take suggestions from the answers, did some more searching on google, and then came up with the answer. I was still very new to programming and had no idea what I was doing