# What is the relationships between Parents, Nodes and Scenes?

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, parent

I'm asking regarding the relationships between Nodes, Scenes and Parents. I'm actually studying JavaFX and is difficult change scenes in the same frame. I founded a way for do that, but actually I don't know how it works. Can you help me figure it out ?

I tried looking for on the Java reference, on youtube and also writing on google the keyword "Scenes Parent" but I didn't found anything that helped me.

```
public class SceneCreator {

  // launching the new scene based on the .fxml file name passed in the argument as a String variable
  // building the scene and setting the value for the instance variable loader
  public static void launchScene (String sceneName) throws IOException {

    // Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource(sceneName));
    Main.setRoot(loader.load());
    Scene scene = new Scene(Main.getRoot());
    Main.getStage().setScene(scene);
    Main.getStage().show();



@FXML
  private void sphereClick() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Sphere button clicked");
    SceneCreator.launchScene("sphere.fxml");
  }
```

Comment: [Parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html), and [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverFlow, Please search very thouroghly before asking a question, but to target the answer here:

The JavaFX `scene` graph is part of the top layer and is the starting
point for constructing a JavaFX application.

It is a hierarchical tree of nodes that represents all of the visual elements of the application’s user interface. It can handle input and can be rendered, refer to the picture[image]

A single element in a scene graph is called a `node`. Each `node` has an `ID`, `style class`, and `bounding volume`.

each node in a scene graph has a `single parent` and `zero or more children`

please read the following book it is around 70 pages but its very helpful, and since you are studying it, there is not time wasted
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/JFXST.pdf

Refer to stackoverflow questions, they can be really helpful and they target your very question, such as this one:

[How to swap screens in a javafx-application in the controller-class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804664/how-to-swap-screens-in-a-javafx-application-in-the-controller-class)

or this one

[How to switch scenes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200845/how-to-switch-scenes-in-javafx)