# JavaFX11 program multiple windows using scenebuilder

Tags: intellij-idea, fxml, scenebuilder, java-11, javafx-11

I am learning how to build program in java FX  using IntelliJ and Scenebuilder  but I have a problem in how to create a program can implement many functions

my questions are

How can I build an application to use multiple windows?

start window includes many choices (many subprograms ) each choice replace the window by its content

how to go back to the main menu window?

Comment: Hopefully https://stackoverflow.com/a/37276108/3579960 would help.
The reason I commented this is because question says "start window includes many choices" which might be better if it's in a Menu.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new Window, you can call `new Stage()`, which creates a new Window, for which you can then set the content by using `set Scene()`.

Don't forget to then show your Stage by using `show()`.