# How to properly display a second fxml file view in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am new to JavaFX and SceneBuilder. I have been stuck for a while now on how to properly display a second view for my application directly from my controller. (If the user clicks the NEXT button, then display this fxml file) This is what I have tried so far:

```
package application.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import application.Main;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class controller1 implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private Stage window;
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    
    @FXML
    private Button whoami;
    @FXML
    private Button next;
    @FXML
    private Label where;
    
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            where.setText("You're in view #1");    // When running my program, this does work
    }
    
    public void event2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            
            where.setText("NEXT was selected.");   // This second button also print to the console
            
            /* Here is where I am a little lost, 
            // after this part, my program gets an error starting with
            // Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
            // I did this approach for my start method in Main.java, and view 1 gets displayed
            // I am happy to learn from any feedback  */

            window.setTitle("View #2!!!!");
            
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/view2.fxml"));
            anchorPane = loader.load();
            
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(anchorPane);
            window.setScene(scene2);
            window.show();  
    }
}
```

This is my Main.java:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
 
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage window;
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    
    // Sets Stage for application:
    @Override      
    public void start(Stage window) throws IOException {

        // window is what I called my primaryStage
        this.window = window;
        this.window.setTitle("View #1");
        this.window.setResizable(false);
        
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/view1.fxml"));
        anchorPane =loader.load();
        
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(anchorPane);
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();  
    }
    
    // Main Method:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
}
```

This is the error trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 

    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
        ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at application.controller.controller1.event2(controller1.java:48)
        ... 58 more
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200845/how-to-switch-scenes-in-javafx

Comment: Thank you, I tried following some of the answers there and in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805134/14593936 too, but unfortunately, I can not get past the same error :( If there are any extra tips please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Alright, could you please share the error stack trace?

Comment: Yes! just edited it into question

Answer (score -1):

The window variable in your controller throws `NullPointerException` because it does not reference the actual window in your Main.java.

An easy workaround for this would be to create a `Stage` variable that you can access from your controller. Here's an example:

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage window;
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    protected static Stage window;

    // Sets Stage for application:
    @Override      
    public void start(Stage window1) throws IOException {
        window = window1;
        // window is what I called my primaryStage
        this.window = window;
        this.window.setTitle("View #1");
        this.window.setResizable(false);
        
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/view1.fxml"));
        anchorPane =loader.load();
        
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(anchorPane);
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();  
    }
    
    // Main Method:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Above here, I've created a `window` variable that references the `window1` variable that the parameter of your `start()` method.

Now to make changes to the window, I can simply do so by referencing the window variable in the Main class. First remove the `window` declaration in your controller. Then access the `window` variable in your Main.java as `Main.window`.

```
public void event2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            
            where.setText("NEXT was selected."); 
             happy to learn from any feedback  */

            Main.window.setTitle("View #2!!!!");
            
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/view2.fxml"));
            anchorPane = loader.load();
            
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(anchorPane);
            Main.window.setScene(scene2);
            Main.window.show();  
    }
```

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider marking it as such. If not, feel free to let me know.

Comment: no, static scope is wrong (nearly, but certainly here) always, instead pass references around as needed. Also:  does this really compile? (2 fields with name window) - even if it does, it's extremely confusing

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the idea, Maurice, It solved my issue! to make it simpler for me; in the protected window I changed the name to window2 and changed the privacy to the public. But everything worked out as intended. :)